# Masking in Python

Tags: python, mask

I'm attempting to arrange the following code so that a digit representing the character place in the word appears below the mask. In other words:

```
  _ _ _
  1 2 3
```

Here's my current code:

```
secretWord = 'dog'

mask = '_'  * len(secretWord)
for i in range (len(secretWord)):
    if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
        mask = mask[:i] + secretWord[i] + mask [i+1:]
for letter in mask:
    print (letter, end='')

print ()
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: You'll need some sort of monospace font to make this work. Not a problem if you're on the command line, but it might be problematic if you're using an IDE

Answer (score 1):

A list representation would help you out here:

```
secretWord = list('dog') # ['d', 'o', 'g']

mask = ['_']  * len(secretWord) # not problematic, since strs are immutable
for i,char in enumerate(secretWord):
    if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
        mask[i] = secretWord[i]
print (''.join(mask))
```

Hope this helps